# not able to setup kubernetes cluster using kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

trying to setup kubernetes cluster using kubeadm, master node is in ready state but when i give kubeadm join token command to worker node its saying tc not found in system path and its getting timed out

i gave kubeadm join command to worker node, it was supposed to join the cluster, but its getting timed out
kubeadm join <MASTER_IP>:6443 --token  --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash <CA_CERT_HASH>

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to serverfault ;)

Please give some more information about your setup - which operating system do you use, which version do you attempt to install as well as the relevant log output.

You are missing the installation of a package that provides the `tc` command and there were some tickets in the past that for example this is the case for some CentOS releases (that's why details are important of what you use).

Something like `sudo dnf install iproute-tc` could help - in Debian like systems `tc` is bundled with `iproute2` so it's there by default.

`tc` is a tool for managing traffic control - see https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/tc.8.html - and is a dependency for kubernetes.